# inserting multiple records gives me an error?

Tags: php, sql

Could you help me when I want to insert several records to my DB it shows me the following error message, right in the base if it lets me enter it but not from PHP
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Insert value list does not match column list

this is the code

```
$insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO progress (folio_solicitud, interventor, paso, status_solicitud) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?);"); 

$insert->execute(array($folio, $datos, 3, 'En proceso', $folio, $datos, 4, 'En proceso', $folio, $datos, 5, 'En proceso', $folio, $datosA, 6, 'En proceso' ));
```

Comment: @miken32 That seems an unfortunate duplicate target. That question was about the columns not being specified in the `insert` statement (and every answer revolves around that), while here OP has specified them.

Comment: @El_Vanja good point, I've updated to one with a that explicitly has a column number mismatch.

Comment: The code presented here seems to match, but a mismatch between columns and values is literally the only way this error would occur, meaning the code given here is not the cause of the error. (Regardless, I would suggest you prepare your query with a single VALUES clause and then execute it 4 times with the different values, to avoid unnecessarily complicating your code with long parameter lists.)